# How to send send mail with attachment (Excel sheet) using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sendmail

I have tried this code but not working for me...

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
     @profile_name='Capricorn',
     @recipients='abc@gmail.com',
     @query= N'set nocount on;select ClientID,ClientName from ClientMaster; set nocount off;',
     @subject='Invoice Not Post',
     @query_attachment_filename='Customers.xlsx',
     @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
     @body=@body,
     @body_format ='HTML'
```

Comment: Use .csv and tab for @query_result_separator, https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/462348/Can-DatabaseMail-attach-a-formatted-Excel-file#bm462706

Comment: **not working** does not mean anything to anyone. Do you mean you don't receive an email? Please be specific. Have you configured your smtp server? Are there any errors in the SQL Server log?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Without attachment its working fine. Now I want to send attchement(excel sheet) with mail.

Comment: So... what happens? Do you get an email without an attachment? Do you get no email? Do you see any errors in the SQL Error log?

Comment: Yes. I received mail without attachment. I am using SQL Server agent where I have created 1 job for sending mail but while executing this job getting error as "Execution of job "abc" failed".

Comment: and so..... what is the detail in the sql agent error log? are there any errors in the SQL Server Log? (3rd time I've asked) can you see a pattern emerging here?